# mp4 video to audio(Opus) + video(av1) mux to mkv using Gstreamer (Pipeline stops at 75%)

Tags: c++, c, audio, video, gstreamer

I'm new to multimedia processing, and I'm trying to create a dynamic pipeline that takes this video sample (https://download.samplelib.com/mp4/sample-5s.mp4), demuxes it, converts audio to Opus codec, then video to av1 codec and muxes them together.

Here is a pipeline I created:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=input.mp4 \
  ! qtdemux name=demux matroskamux name=mux \
  ! filesink location=output.mkv demux.audio_0 \
  ! queue ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! opusenc ! mux. demux.video_0 \
  ! queue ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! av1enc ! mux.
```

It converts the audio to Opus using opusenc and video to av1 using av1enc, then muxes them. However, for some reason, when the video is processed by 75%, pipeline suddenly stops forever without any further progress (the process was running for ~8 hours, so I think I indeed can claim that it runs forever).

Can someone suggest why it may happen and what can/should I do? I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 of the newest version and Gstreamer of the newest version.

Comment: BTW, when I'm using h264 instead of av1, everything's fine. Can it be some sort of incompability between codecs?

Comment: Cropping the video to 4 secconds resolves the issue, but the video doesn't play. It starts, lasts for 1 second (without audio) and stops.

Answer (score 0):

What is the default latency of `av1enc`? It may be that the queues are too small to compensate the latency. Perhaps `lag-in-frames` property has an impact here. Or increase the queue sizes.